# External authentication using Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

We got our own central session management. Generally user can authenticate over it with an username and password, and as a result he gets an session_id. All other operations are done with that session_id. Let's say that the session management is accessed by a XML RPC.

I have two cases to implement:

- Central web application made in Spring, which has login form
- External web applications also made in Spring, which are relying on
  passed session_id only.

Few more notices regarding system:
- session_id is stored in a cookie (after successful login, I have to add cookie to a response)
- every page request has to check session_id validity in session management system

I'm quite new to Spring, so I'm struggling to understand where and how to implement my custom logic.

My questions are:

1. What parts of a system I have to implement to have my own login
   logic (got to have access to a response object too - to set cookie)?
   *I tryed something with extending UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and implementing my own
   AuthenticationManager, but I'm not sure that I'm going the right
   way.*
2. Is there point where/how can I implement my "every request session
       check" in Spring Security manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- session_id is stored in a cookie (after successful login, I have to add cookie to a response)

Do this in a AuthenticationSuccessHandler that is configured into your `<form-login>` element:

```
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

- External web applications also made in Spring, which are relying on passed session_id only.

Create a new filter where you check for the session_id cookie.   If the cookie is not present or if it is invalid redirect to the central web application for the user to log in.   If the cookie is present and valid and the user isn't already authenticated then create a new `Authentication` and add it to the `SecurityContextHolder`.

Take a look at RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter() for an example of what you want to do in your filter.

Add this filter to the filter chain using the `<custom-filter>` element.

Comment: Adding cookies to a response: I tried to, in "MySuccessAuthHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler" and I tried it also in "MyAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter". In both casess (tested in debuger) the methods are invoked, but response does not contains any cookies I added to.